# Word analysis in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, cosine-distance, text

I have a list of documents which look like this:

```
["Display is flickering"]
["Battery charger is broken"]
["Hard disk is making noises"]
```

These text documents are just free text.
I have processed with tokenization, lemmatization, stop words removal, and now I want to assign tags based on a list of words. Example:

```
{"#display":["display","screen","lcd","led"]}
{"#battery":["battery","power cord","charger","drains"]}
{"#hard disk":["hard disk","performance","slow"]}
```

After text normalization I have:

```
["Display is flickering"] -> ["display","flicker"]
```

What technique is recommended to compare document: ["display","flicker"]
with my dictionary of words and return which value matches the best?
In this case I would like:

```
["display","flicker"] = "#display":"display"
["battery","charger","broke"] = "#battery":"charger"
```

Basically it compares Document A in tokens with a list B of other documents and return which document in list B with more common matches.

I'm using [TF](http://stevenloria.com/finding-important-words-in-a-document-using-tf-idf/), but want to know if there are other techniques, code samples to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) in order to compare whole phrases. I am aware about two models: Google's [word2vec](http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec) and Stanford's [GloVe](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Now, word embedding works best with, well - words. However, you could concatenate every word in your phrase and re-train the models. Afterwards, you could calculate their similarity (say, with cosine similarity) and see how similar your whole phrases are semantically.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is called multiclass and multilabel text classification. Check the tutorials [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).